# Django model import from app to onether model

Tags: django, django-models

[MqSQL db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Bf4S.png)Good Day. Could you please give me a directie.
I has extended basic User model and
I need to import it to another app Django. Could you please explain me a bit how and there is my mistake.?

models.py user extended model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    hb_photo = models.ImageField('User photo', default='incognito.png', upload_to='users/%Y/%m/%d/')
    hb_phone = models.CharField('Phone number', max_length=50, null=True)
    hb_department = models.CharField('Department name', max_length=50, null=True)

    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'User profiles {self.user.first_name} {self.user.last_name}'
```

models.py there i truing to import User extendet model

```
from higabase.members.models import Profile

class NewPlacement(models.Model):

    np_nationality = CountryField('Nationality', null=True)
    np_coming_date = models.DateField('Coming date', null=True)
    ex_test_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    location = models.ForeignKey('FeelFlexLocation', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    ff_hb_photo = models.ManyToManyField('User photo', default=Profile.hb_photo)
    ff_hb_phone = models.ManyToManyField('Phone number', default=Profile.hb_phone)
    ff_hb_department = models.ManyToManyField('Department name', default=Profile.hb_department)
```

Then i truing to makemigrations.

```
    from higabase.members.models import Profile
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'higabase.members'
(venv) PS C:\Users\Feelflex\Desktop\TESTING2\higabase>
```

I do not understend how i can fix it :(

Comment: Can you share your file structure?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Bf4S.png

Comment: I can send a project link if its helps.

Comment: Thats not the project file structure. Its database structure.

Answer (score 0):

If members is your appname and higabase is your project, then

```
from members.models import Profile
```

should work in any app.